# AngularJS - Scope variable not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS controller (HomeCtrl) that loads data from HTTP, if it detects that there has been some data in LocalStorage.

This check works on the entry of the controller.

```
var datOld = {
  APIDataService.getOldData($scope.searchTerms, totalPages, 1)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Now getting data and applying it')
    $scope.records = data;
  }
```

I have `$records` in `ng-repeat` in view. It doesn't get updated.
I have uploaded the entire project on Github for reference.
https://github.com/kirobo/AngularApp

I tried to do `$scope.apply()` too, but it doesn't update either.
I would be glad if someone can point out what the error is or if something I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `$records` a typo?

Comment: Can't be sure without looking at your HTML. But if you are really using '$records', that is wrong. It should be just `records` in ng-repeat.

Comment: Apologies, its $scope.records

Comment: I have uploaded a link to github repo. Kindly have a look. I spent a lot of time to get this error to solve, I'm at my wits end. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Put `{{records}}` somewhere in your HTML and check whether it is updating and check the actual value assigned to $scope.records

Comment: this is pretty hard to debug from your repository. Please try to create a jsfiddle with the minimum set of information needed

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo but why are you doing, var datOld = {APIDataService...  ???

Answer (score 0):

Declare your scope variable like this

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.records = null;
```

then when you fetch

```
APIDataService.getOldData($scope.searchTerms, totalPages,1).then(function(data) {
 console.log('Now getting data and applying it')
 $scope.data.recods = data;
}
```

And use $scope.data.records in html. Will work like a charm

Comment: Hey, tried to do that.
Unfortunately, it's not working.
I can see console.log($scope.data.records) but it's not updating in views.
Here's github repo for reference. 
https://github.com/kirobo/AngularApp